# Android gradient drawable not showing on button

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-xml, android-drawable

I am rather new to StackOverFlow - so if you have problems with this question, please tell me in the comments.

I'm creating a basic Android app with a material button with a background set to a gradient drawable like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:angle="0"
        android:endColor="#027FEE"
        android:startColor="#2CC6F2" />
</shape>
```

MainActivity:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
 >

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="@drawable/mygrad"
        android:text="Gradient Test"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The problem is - this used to work, but I returned to the project 2 days later and the gradient is nowhere to be seen:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3Uus.png)

Although the gradient *does* show in the mini preview, it is not seen anywhere else:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzBaQ.png)

I'm not sure why I'm encountering this problem as I'm following everything by the book.

Cheers,
Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please replace

```
android:backgroundTint="@drawable/mygrad"
```

with

```
android:background="@drawable/mygrad"
```